# Let $a>0$ and $b>0$. Prove that $\sqrt{ab} \le (a+b)/2$.

Tags: inequality, means

Let $a>0$ and $b>0$. Prove that $\sqrt{ab} \le (a+b)/2$.

Here is what I have tried:
Let $a \le b$. Multiplying both sides of this inequality by $a$ results in $a^2 \le ab$. It follows that $a \le \sqrt{ab}$. We can do the same process with $b$ to find that $a \le \sqrt{ab} \le b$.

Similarly we can add $a$ to both sides, then divide by 2 to give this inequality: $a \le (a+b)/2 \le b$.

However, I have no way to compare $\sqrt{ab}$ and $(a+b)/2$.

Comment: Take the square of both sizes and use the fact that $a^{2}+b^{2}\geq2ab
 $ (do you see why?).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543253/how-can-i-prove-frac2xyxy-leq-sqrtxy-leq-fracxy2, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114615/if-0ab-prove-that-a-sqrtab-fracab2b, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904827/how-to-prove-that-fracab2-geq-sqrtab-for-a-b0

Comment: This is an overkill but you can [prove](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Proofs_of_AM-GM) AM-GM inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since squares are non-negative, you can use that
$$
(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2 \geq 0.
$$