# How to go upon proving $\frac{x+y}2 \ge \sqrt{xy}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, means

I'm trying to prove this but am having some difficulty.

For any $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ we have
$$\frac{x+y}2 \ge \sqrt{xy}.$$

---

So far what I have gotten to is $\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{2} $

After this point I don't know what to do. To get to this point:

$$y \geq 0 $$
$$\implies y \geq y$$
$$\implies xy \geq xy$$
$$\implies 2xy \geq xy$$
$$\implies x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2} \geq xy$$
$$\implies (x+y)^{2} \geq xy$$

Sqrt both sides to get:

$$\implies x+y \geq \sqrt{xy}$$
$$\implies\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{2}$$

Comment: How did you get to that point? (I actually don't see a way to get there without solving the problem all the way, so I'm curious.)

Comment: I updated the post to show my work

Comment: Why have you deleted your work? I think it was beneficial to the question.

Comment: The work leads to a dead end, so I feel it will mislead anyone else reading it.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64881/proving-the-am-gm-inequality-for-2-numbers
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904827/how-to-prove-that-fracab2-geq-sqrtab-for-a-b0
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114615/if-0ab-prove-that-a-sqrtab-fracab2b
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150895/let-a0-and-b0-prove-that-sqrtab-le-ab-2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543253/how-can-i-prove-frac2xyxy-leq-sqrtxy-leq-fracxy2

Comment: And if you denote $x=a^2$ and $y=b^2$, then you can look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241741/simple-algebra-question-proving-a2b2-geqslant-2ab
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320244/show-that-2-xy-x2-y2-for-x-is-not-equal-to-y
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470221/prove-the-inequality-xy-leq-frac12x2y2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943994/show-that-for-all-real-numbers-a-and-b-ab-le-1-2a2b2

Comment: BTW you can use `$\implies$` $\implies$ or `$\Rightarrow$` $\Rightarrow$. It looks a bit better than $=>$.

Comment: @LeoDenni Even if your work would prove to be misleading if we read it, we are here to help you and identify any errors in your working out to verify whether or not you have proved the inequality. From the looks of it, you have errors, and so we can now most certainly help you out. That is what the MSE is for :)

Comment: Here is another link discussing the matter $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality There are also other links accessible from the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(x-y)^2 \ge 0\\ x^2+2xy+y^2-4xy \ge 0 \\(x+y)^2 \ge 4xy\\\frac {x+y}2 \ge \sqrt{xy}$$

Comment: I have no idea what is going on here

Comment: Any square is greater than zero, for the first line.  I added a step.  From the third to fourth, take the square root

Comment: Well first of all, $(x-y)^{2} \neq x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2}$. And also how can you subtract $4xy$ from the equation in the second line without giving any reason? How do I know the inequality is still true?

Comment: @LeoDenni $$x^2+2xy+y^2-4xy=x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$$

Comment: from the second to the third I subtracted $4xy$ from both sides and noted that $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$

Comment: I kind of get it, but I'm still confused. If I have $x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2}$, how am I able to subtract $-4xy$ from that and keep the inequality true? It just seems like it is out of no where

Comment: @LeoDenni The point is that $x^2+2xy+y^2-4xy$ is the same as $x^2-2xy+y^2$ - this is because $2xy-4xy=-2xy$. Really there's steps in between - $(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2=x^2-2xy+y^2+4xy-4xy=x^2+2xy+y^2-2xy$.

Comment: Okay I understand now, but I'm not satisfied. I just don't see how you knew to make that jump. How was I suppose to know to do that? (Please bear in mind I'm very new to proofs)

Comment: Understanding a proof is very different from finding it.  To understand it, you just need to follow through step by step, filling in as necessary to make sure you can see where each comes from.  I've seen this one before, so finding it is easy.  The fact that $(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2=4xy$ comes up with some frequency, so if I hadn't seen it before I would have been tempted to take what you have to prove, multiply by $2$ to clear the fraction and square to get rid of the root.  The more proofs you read, the more you get a feel for them, which makes finding them much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Based on my work in my original post, is there a way for me to have proven it from my last line? Or that was  a dead end?

Comment: That was a dead end because your RHS is too small.  Just putting in the factor $2$ in the fourth line is too poor an approximation.  If $x$ is close to $y$ the inequality you are trying to prove is rather close.  A different proof starts out with $(\sqrt x - \sqrt y)^2 \ge 0$.  You might see if you can get from there to the end.

Comment: I know that this is more than an year old, but, I feel like one of Leo Denni's questions was not answered properly.  To reproduce this proof, think about it forwards and _then_ write it formally. Start with the statement you wish to prove, manipulate it into a true statement, and if you can, go from the true statement to the statement you wish to prove. If you see that you can't write the proof backwards, then that is a red flag to check your proof for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start from the beginning and simplify what we want to show:

$$\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$$

By multiplying both side by $2$, we will get:

$$x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$$

Now, subtracting $2\sqrt{xy}$ from both sides, we left with:

$$x-2\sqrt{xy}+y\geq 0$$

Now, a question:

Why $x-2\sqrt{xy}-y$ is indeed greater(or equal) than zero?

Closer look on the above expression, one might see that its equal to $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$

So, if we are given two positive real numbers $x$ and $y$, then without loss of generality we can say that $x>y$(why?), therefore $\sqrt{x}>\sqrt{y}$(prove that).
Hence:
$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}>0$$

And...

Comment: You are starting from what we want to prove and have not justified the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, that is my point. The simplification is very useful here;  after seeing what last expression is, the OP might find the right argument for a proof. Is that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure how you want me to answer that question. You did the manipulation and you got it to be greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: @RossMillikan Actually, all those steps are iff's, so what he did is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment on your attempt to prove this inequality rather than answer to your question. Just to show that it was not completely dead end, as you wrote in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632763/how-to-go-upon-proving-fracxy2-ge-sqrtxy/1632965#comment3329294_1632763).

You wrote that you tried this:

> So far what I have gotten to is $\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{2} $
>
> After this point I don't know what to do. To get to this point:
>
> $$y \geq 0 $$
>   $$\implies y \geq y$$
>   $$\implies xy \geq xy$$
>   $$\implies 2xy \geq xy$$
>   $$\implies x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2} \geq xy$$
>   $$\implies (x+y)^{2} \geq xy$$
>
> Sqrt both sides to get:
>
> $$\implies x+y \geq \sqrt{xy}$$
>   $$\implies\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{2}$$

---

What you could do know could be ask yourself: Well, I want to prove stronger inequality. Could I get it by similar approach?

So we start from the end. You want to get
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \sqrt{xy}$$
which is the same as 
$$x+y \geq 2\sqrt{xy}.$$
Relation between these two is the same as in the last step of your attempt - just divided by $2$. If we try to go one step back in the same way as above, this can be obtained as the square root of
$$
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^2 &\ge 4xy\\
x^2+2xy+y^2 &\ge 4xy\\
\end{align*}
$$

So at this point you could think about: "How could I get $x^2+2xy+y^2 \ge 4xy$?" Maybe after playing a bit with this expression you would found a way to prove this. (However, now you already know how to show this from other answers.)

Comment: And since I have already posted so many links in comments, maybe it is ok to post a few more - other posts about the weaker inequality, which you have shown in your attempt (to be more precise, about some equivalent or very similar inequality): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/how-can-i-prove-that-xy-leq-x2y2, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920605/inequality-x2y2xy-ge-0, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439494/prove-that-a2abb2-ge-0